# Leaflet Maps not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

I'd like to keep javascript in an external file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <title>Map</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js">
    </script> -->
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the js file

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RlYmFkcmkiLCJhIjoiY2ptcjh1YmNlMXluajNxcDU0b3NrOWowbiJ9.kGcSMPD0cZyz0tLOTIIilw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Can someone help me in understanding what is going wrong? I've created a jsfiddle (as to my understanding). But no luck there too!
https://jsfiddle.net/vxb0ces9/

Comment: With JSFiddle you can specify libraries similarly as in your HTML, or using the "Resources" tab on the left. Updated your JSFiddle to add Leaflet CSS and JS files: https://jsfiddle.net/d0ajtsf4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS in your JSFiddle looks like this:

```css
#mapid {
  height: 400 px;
  width: 600 px;
}
```

[CSS Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#length-units) should be specified without white space between the number and the unit: (emphasis mine)

> The format of a length value [...] is a <number> (with or without a decimal point) **immediately followed** by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.).

Therefore in your case simply fixing your CSS to:

```css
#mapid {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

...solves your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/hym0bo9p/